# How to scan barcode with zxing and return with jsonp?

Tags: json, html, angularjs, zxing

I am wondering if there is a way of starting zxing from the browser (as described here https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-From-Web-Pages) and getting the result with a jsonp callback or at least as a json, xml or whatever else than a web redirection ?

If fact, I am looking for a nice way of integrating zxing with my website w/o reloading my website (done with angular) and losing previously entered data.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not really. It's an app outside the web browser. About all it can do is trigger the browser, and that means opening a URL. It's not something running within a web page that can execute callbacks.